# SQLite and delete command

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
bool ret = false;
try
{
    SQLiteConnection sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + m_dbName);
    sqlConn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
    sqlComm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + szTablename + " WHERE name=" + name + "";
    SQLiteDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlComm);
    if (null == sqlAdapter)
    {
        ret = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = true;
    }
    sqlConn.Close();
    return ret;
}
catch (SQLiteException sqlEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sqlEx.Message);
    return false;
}
```

I have that code to delete a row in an SQLite database, but nothing is done after I click the delete button.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: specifically be careful of injection where user input is formatted into the query.  For SqlLite, look into ? params for the name.

Comment: I also would suggest to use bind variables instead of string concatenation! Looks more cleaner and prevents SQL injection. Please Keep in mind to ever use bind variables...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `DataAdapter` you could just execute the command directly:

```
using(SQLiteConnection sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + m_dbName))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    //create command

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You shouldn't swallow any exceptions that get thrown from the `ExecuteNonQuery` method unless you can sensibly handle them. You should use parameterised queries instead of manually creating the queries by concatenating strings. You should also make sure you close the connection after you have finished using it as shown.

Comment: Thanks but I still can't delete the row

Comment: @JoeMo - I've updated the answer to just execute the command directly since you don't appear to be using a `DataSet` you need to delete from.

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(con))
{
    com.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + szTablename + " WHERE name='" + name + "';";
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer, as well as context and cause.

Comment: This post is on a review queue as a "low quality" answer only because you did not explain your code. Code only solutions are frowned-upon on StackOverflow because they tend to require more guesswork and time of the people scanning answers for solutions. If you want to avoid this being deleted, please edit your answer and explain it. Thank you!

Comment: No need to use com.Dispose() here since the com object will be automatically disposed once the code exits the using block.

Answer (score 0):

Try with single quotes:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + szTablename+" WHERE name='"+name+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `like` instead of `=`
inside the query:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + szTablename+" WHERE name="+name+""
```

as this:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM " + szTablename+" WHERE name like "+name+""
```